# Access Key S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

#### Question

I currently have a s3 bucket that is publicly accessible but I want to make it is that you need to provide a access key on the request.

Or in other words would like to make it so only users with the api key are able to write to the bucket.

Comment: You mean aws credentials?

Comment: How would you identify/authenticate these users? Are they staff, or are they users of an app? Or are you wanting to allow anyone with a special URL to be able to access the bucket? Do you only want them to WRITE to the bucket, or would you also want them to be able to List the contents of the bucket and Download files?

Comment: I would want them to be able to list,read, and write to the folder. For authenticating I was thinking of either just only providing the api key to those required or using IAM. This task is for integrating other applications

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to grant access to Amazon S3 for a specific users would be to use AWS credentials.

There are two main sets of credentials:

- **Permanent credentials** assigned to **IAM Users** (Access Key, Secret Key), *or*
- **Temporary credentials** generated by the [AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) (Access Key, Secret Key, Security Token)

For staff of your company, you would normally created **IAM Users** and provide them with their (permanent) credentials.

For users of an application, you would normally have them **authenticate to an app that you write**. Your app would authenticate them against some credentials store (eg a database, or Active Directory) and it would then **generate Temporary Credentials** that have associated permissions. The users can then use those Temporary Credentials for a limited time period (eg 1 hour).

In both cases, the provided credentials can then be used to **make API calls to AWS**, or used with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Both types of credentials can also be assigned permissions (eg List, Read, Write) for particular Amazon S3 buckets, or even folders (Prefixes) within an S3 bucket.

There is also another way of providing temporary access by using an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a **time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object**. This is a URL that includes a calculated number that permits temporary access to private content in Amazon S3. Each URL can only be used to download a specific object -- it cannot be used for a whole bucket. It can also permit uploading to a bucket, but cannot be used to List the contents of a bucket.